# Twilio - get error code on sms send failure

Tags: php, rest, twilio

Our code sends twilio sms messages by doing the following:

```
// send the text message to the member's mobile phone 
try {

// attempt to send the message through Twilio
$tw_msg = $twilio_client->messages->create(
    "+1".$recipient['address'],
    array (
        'From' => "+1".$org['twilio_number'],
        'Body' => $txtmsg,
        'StatusCallback' => CALLBACK_LINK.'/text_message_handler.php'
    )
);

// else trap the error since the message could not be sent and the callback routine is not called
} catch (Exception $e) {

    // process the text message error 
    process_text_msg_error($db, $e, $org, $msg, $recipient);
}
```

In the v4 library we would get the error code by doing the following:

```
// get the twilio error components 
$twilio_error_status = $e->getStatus();
$twilio_error_code = $e->getCode();
$twilio_error_msg = $e->getMessage();
```

This is not giving us what we expected using the V5 library.  How do we get the error status and code using the V5 lib?

Comment: What are you getting with the v5 library when you process the error?

Comment: it is an array I will have to email it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks to me like you need to update one of the methods you call on the exception to get the status code. The exception is now a [`RestException`](https://twilio.github.io/twilio-php/5.12.1/class-Twilio.Exceptions.RestException.html) and has the method [`getStatusCode()`](https://twilio.github.io/twilio-php/5.12.1/class-Twilio.Exceptions.RestException.html#_getStatusCode). You should update to:

```
// get the twilio error components 
$twilio_error_status = $e->getStatusCode();
$twilio_error_code = $e->getCode();
$twilio_error_msg = $e->getMessage();
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Yes that gave us the 400 code.  How about the other two fields, how do we get those?  We are wanting the specific 5 digit error code.  The 400 just means the https request failed to create a message.

Comment: Are the `getCode` and `getMessage` methods not giving the 5 digit error code?

Comment: My bad!  They were working, I failed to add them to the log file.  Thanks my friend.